# Show an image in Colab Markdown Cell

Tags: image, markdown, google-colaboratory

I am trying to add an Image to a Colab markdown cell. I uploaded it to Colab, so it is under /content/test.jpg

however I can’t seem to get it working that the image displays in a markdown cell.

```
![img](/content/test.jpg)
```

doesn’t work.

thanks!

Comment: Interesting. I tried droping a image there (*in the `text`* section), the imagen then is changed to a base64 string - you can check [here-default Colab page](https://colab.research.google.com/) and see that the image embed in the "text" section is actually a base64 string instead the path of a file. I think it's better to embed an image as follows: `<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6EHSlhnE6Ck/hqdefault.jpg" />`